# Los datos de la sesión no se eliminan al cerrar la ventana del navegador en Laravel Auth

Tags: php, laravel, auth

En laravel "6.0.4" estoy tratando de modificar el login para eliminar los datos de la sesión si se cierra la ventana del explorador, hasta ahora he intentado lo siguiente Session::flush();

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
   // Validar las credenciales del usuario
   $this->validateLogin($request);

   // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
   // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
   // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
   if (method_exists($this, 'hasTooManyLoginAttempts') &&
         $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
         $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
   }

      // Eliminar los datos de la sesión anterior
       Session::flush();

   // Intentar autenticar al usuario
   if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
       return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

   // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
   // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
   // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
   $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

      return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
   }
```

Si alguien me puede guiar sobre que estoy haciendo mal, mucho se los agradecería, llevo dias leyendo pero no doy con la solucion a este problema de seguridad, ya que si un usuario administrador cierra la ventana y se loguea un usuario común, este hereda los permisos del usuario administrador que simplemente cerro la ventana del explorador

Comment: sera el cache de laravel???

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover, realemente no se a que se debe ese error, aún no lo he solucionado